# PHP's cURL: How to connect over HTTPS?

Tags: php

I need to do a simple GET request to EC2 Query API with regular URL encoded query string. The protocol is HTTPS. How would I send the request with the help of PHP's cURL.

Answer (score 18):

Example:

```
$url = "https://example.com";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  2);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($result);
```

**CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER**

Check if peer certificate is valid or invalid/expired.

**CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST** quoting from [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

> 1 to check the existence of a common
>   name in the SSL peer certificate. 2 to
>   check the existence of a common name
>   and also verify that it matches the
>   hostname provided.

Comment: Could you describe why SSL_VERIFYPEER and SSL_VERIFYHOST are required?

Answer (score 4):

Sending a request via curl, to an HTTPS URL, is not that hard by itself, in terms of PHP code.

Something like this should do perfectly fine *(I just tried this portion of code on my machine, Windows, PHP 5.3)* :

```
$url = 'https://.../...';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $data;
```

And it outputs the result fine : the same thing I get in my browser when trying to access the `https://` URL ; except for the CSS, of course.

You might want to take a look at the manual page of the [`curl_setopt`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) function : there are a lot of options, and some of those might be useful, in your specific case :-)

Here, I used `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` ; not sure you'll need those with Amazon, but I had to use them, else this portion of code didn't work -- but that might be related to the fact that the certificate I'm using is self-signed... Try with and without those, and you'll quickly find out if you need them.

Comment: @Sarfraz > ergh, damn copy-paste *(I copied-pasted an URL from my browser, without noticing it didn't add the 's' as it used to on my previous server)* ;; I've edited my answer to correct that ;; thanks for the comment :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to configure CURL to blindly accept the certificate you can set the CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER option to false.

```
$url = 'https://www.example.com/abc';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Blindly accept the certificate
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($response);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use Zend Framework and the cURL adapter to help with this task. Details [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.client.adapters.html)

Answer (score 0):

This code can use to retrieve https requests

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://serverurl.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$data1 = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```