# Get HTML content from a given HTTPS url

Tags: php, parsing, curl, file-get-contents

I have to download the HTML content from a HTTPS url to parse few links.

I can do it without any problem from non HTTPS url using:

file_get_contents

I tried with this code:

```
    $ch = curl_init('http://kickass.so/best-new-restaurant-s01e01-italian-cuisine-hdtv-x264-daview-t10113796.html');
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
    CURLOPT_CAINFO => 'I:/dev/ServerPHP/movieGather/UniServerZ/core/apache2/server_certs/server.crt',
));

if (false === curl_exec($ch)) {
    echo "Error while loading page: ", curl_error($ch), "\n";
}
```

but it doesnt works. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2):

Try with this,

```
$url = 'https://www.example.com/abc';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Blindly accept the certificate
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

// decode response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($response);
```

see more options at here

```
http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know, and trust, the source, and the source will always be the same site, then don't put it through strict SSL verification.

This is from another SO answer, [PHP's cURL: How to connect over HTTPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306196/phps-curl-how-to-connect-over-https) :

```
$url = 'https://www.example.com/abc';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Blindly accept the certificate
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($response);
```

Comment: I tried your solution but the var_dump give me something like this:

string(11452) "‹í}ërÛFÖào©jß¡‡¤OIðNÝ\²dÇNlÇc)™Ìçu©@ƒ„¢a\D1_R5±¶j÷1ööQæIöœîÆ• EÚ¢f²

etc etc

Comment: Updated and added verifyhost false. Does that make any difference? Does your server support SSL, and does it work in other places/sites/etc? Is the content being sent gzipped?

Comment: Thank you for your help.

I have tried the script with different HTTPS urls and it works....

but im not able to extract the HTML content from this url:

https://kickass.so/best-new-restaurant-s01e01-italian-cuisine-hdtv-x264-daview-t10113796.html

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
function nget($url)
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, TRUE);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9']);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_1_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36');

    $content = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $content;
}

$url = 'https://example.com';
$m = nget($url);
var_dump($m);
```